# Detect the gray level of a surface

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, colors, grayscale

I'm  looking  just for an idea/conception to resolve my problem.

I need to **CHECK** if the color of a surface does not exceed a certain gray level. So I thought to calculate its luminance.

Problem is that [colors](http://www.colorpicker.com/) like this one `#BCB0F5` will give me an acceptable gray level, however the color of the surface must not look that blue for the human eyes. It must look (for human eyes) just as a certain gray level (black and white).

How can I resolve this problem ?
Thank you for any hints.

Comment: convert the BC, B0 and F5 to decimal values, which will give you the levels of red, green and blue. then in order to have a gray color you would have to make them all the same, so you could find an average of these, and get your gray color...

Comment: #BCB0F5 is a hexadecimal value of the color... it is RGB value which means it has it's Red, Green and Blue components. In that order you have #RED-GREEN-BLUE as hex values. each 2 hex numbers represent a whole color value, so red would be BC, green would be B0 and F5 would be blue...

Comment: @Ubica Thank you, I removed my comment because I understood before you answered, sorry. But I do not want to convert the color above to gray level. I just look for a method to tell me if it is of a gray level for the human eyes and not a blue like this

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you want to check the gray level, then make it a gray counterpart of the color in question and do the check. Leave the color as it is, but create your gray for the checking purpose. If you want to make it just appear gray then try to bring the numbers closer together but not the same...

Comment: What you're looking for is the [chromaticity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromaticity) of a colour. You may wish to convert your colour to a perceptual colour model like [L\*a\*b*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space).

Comment: Calculate the [colour difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) from a pure grey (a = 0, b = 0). If the luminance does not exceed your specified level and the Euclidean distance of the chromaticity is not a [Noticeable Difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-noticeable_difference) (< 2.3) then you're good to go.

Comment: Good idea indeed. You can make your comment as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you. @nelfin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a perceptual model of colour, we can talk of a particular colour's luminance and chromaticity (it's "brightness" and it's "quality"). By converting the samples you have from RGB to CIELAB (via [ColorPy](http://markkness.net/colorpy/ColorPy.html) say), you can filter out colours which are brighter than your desired grey (`L_sample` > `L_grey`) and whose distance from the white point are greater than a [JND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-noticeable_difference) (e.g. `sqrt(a_sample**2 + b_sample**2) > 2.3`)

Comment: Thank you very for mentioning ColorPy. I never heard about it before.

Comment: No problem, I hope that you can sort out everything out.